# Azure Log Analytics Workspace not collecting data

Tags: azure, log-analytics-workspace

I have an Azure log analytics workspace. This instance is connected via Diagnostic Settings log of a resource this workspace. However, data just doesnt arrive even several days later. I have other resources that successfully pipe data into this LAW.

Initially I felt it was a problem with the LAW, so I created a new LAW and wired the resource to it. Still no logs (or even tables for that matter).

I next associated this new LAW with another resource in the environment to rule anything being wrong with the original resource. But again no logs are collected. I have waited for more than an hour.

I checked and we have not reached any limits on log streaming. The LAW instances are both Pay-as-you-go.